# Can I delete unneeded app IDs from the iPhone Developer Programming Portal?

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

I have the $99 Apple developer account. I created many app IDs in the iPhone Developer Programming Portal. Now I am unable to delete those app IDs. Is there any way to delete those unwanted app IDs?

Also, how many apps can I develop using the $99 Apple ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are developers with well over 100 apps in the App store.  I haven't seen any reports of them hitting some limit, unless they are also violating some other App store rule.

App IDs seem to be permanent immutable identifiers in Apple's databases.  There is no way to remove them.  The only hope might be for Apple to provide some way to hide them from view.

Comment: This has changed now. Apple is now letting everyone delete the app IDs. Not all, but many.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop an unlimited number of apps, so your app IDs aren't hurting anything.

Comment: No, I don't know of any way. If you created an app but haven't submitted a binary (submitted the app for review) after 90 days you'll get a notice that the app will be removed. 30 days later it will be removed automatically.

Comment: Whoever downvoted my accurate answer, it would be nice to at least know why. Be brave, tell me why you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, Apple seems to have implemented a new feature in the redesigned portal. The details are as follows ::

http://www.tuaw.com/2013/04/07/devjuice-provisioning-portal-redesigned-allows-deletion-of-som/

We can now delete many (but not all) of the unused AppIDs in the account.